# How do I compare two files in IDEAScript?

Tags: ideascript

I have two databases in IDEA: Database A & Database B.  I want to compare the `Quantity` field from these two files and both Databases have a key of `RecordID`.  I would like to create an IDEAScript Macro to perform this process rather than do it manually.  Can someone outline how to create this macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CompareDB function in IDEAScript.  Example Code:

```
Set db1 = Client.OpenDatabase("DatabaseA.IMD")
Set DoCompare = db1.CompareDB
DoCompare.AddMatchKey "RecordID", "RecordID", "A"
DoCompare.PerformTask "Output.imd", "", "QUANTITY", "QUANTITY", "DatabaseB.imd"
Set DoCompare = Nothing
Set db1 = Nothing
Client.CloseDatabase "DatabaseA.IMD"
Client.OpenDatabase "Output.imd"
```